# My code does not show days after today

Tags: android

I want to display only current week values in a calendar. I am using this example code:

[Custom Calendar in Android | Android Calendar Example with full source code](http://www.androidhub4you.com/2012/10/custom-calendar-in-android.html?showComment=1374298656772#c7739428050175524218)

and editing a few lines to get a single row which shows current week dates.

The result looks like this:

[image: Calendar]

... but my code shows only up to today's date, and does not show the date of tomorrow or day after tomorrow. What do I do?

I want something like this:

```
   Sun Mon Tues  Wednes Thurs Fri sat
   21  22   23    24     25    26  27
```

but my code shows:

```
  Sun Mon Tues  Wednes Thurs Fri sat
   21  22   1    2      3     4  5
```

I changed this code from example code:

```
 // Current Month Days
  for (int i = 1; i <= daysInMonth; i++) {
     Log.d(currentMonthName, String.valueOf(i) + " "
       + getMonthAsString(currentMonth) + " " + yy);
     if (i == getCurrentDayOfMonth()) {
       list.add(String.valueOf(i) + "-BLUE" + "-"
          + getMonthAsString(currentMonth) + "-" + yy);
     } else {
       list.add(String.valueOf(i) + "-WHITE" + "-"
         + getMonthAsString(currentMonth) + "-" + yy);
     }
  }
```

with this code:

```
 // Current Month Days
 int startDate = 0;

for (int i = 1; i <= daysInMonth; i++) {
    Log.d(currentMonthName, String.valueOf(i) + " "
            + getMonthAsString(currentMonth) + " " + yy);
     startDate=getCurrentDayOfMonth()-(list.size() % 7);
        System.out.println("**********"+startDate);
       if (i == getCurrentDayOfMonth()) {

        list.add(String.valueOf(i) + "-BLUE" + "-"
                + getMonthAsString(currentMonth) + "-" + yy);

        break;
    } else {


        list.add(String.valueOf(i) + "-WHITE" + "-"
                + getMonthAsString(currentMonth) + "-" + yy);
    }
}

//removing itmem fro list
System.out.println("----------------------"+startDate);
System.out.println(list.size());
for(int k=1;k<=startDate;k++){
    System.out.println("Item remove"+k);
    list.remove(0);
}
```

Comment: Remove `break` statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (i == getCurrentDayOfMonth()) {

        list.add(String.valueOf(i) + "-BLUE" + "-"
                + getMonthAsString(currentMonth) + "-" + yy);

        break;
    }
```

In there, remove the break. As soon as you hit "today" you break out of the for loop.